# Problem with drupal 7 multisite installation

Tags: 7, multi-sites

OS: UBUNTU 11.10

What I want to achieve:

www.example.local     **Main Installation**

www.example1.local    **Installation inside sites folder**

I took the following steps:

Installed drupal 7 as normal installation in the folder `/var/www/example`.

in **/etc/hosts** added the following:

```
127.0.0.1   www.example.local

127.0.0.1   www.example1.local
```

Then in **/etc/apache2/sites-available** ::

`ServerName www.example.local`

`DocumentRoot /var/www/example`

in `example` file.

and

`ServerName www.example1.local`

`DocumentRoot /var/www/example/sites/www.example1.local`

in `www.example1.local` file.

I created folder

> /var/www/example/sites/www.example1.local

and copied default.settings.php and made a `settings.php` from it.

Now , when I go to www.example.local I get the normal(main) installation it works fine.

But when I go to `www.example1.local` I see the list of files in the `www.example1.local` **folder**

[image]

What is the step I am missing?
Or did I do something wrong ? Thank you in advance.

PS: I have not made any change in settings.php of the subsite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentroot is not proper for the second case.
It should be like this

```
ServerName www.example1.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/example
```